# Javascript: How to evaluate a for loop with ternary operators in the 2nd & 3rd statements

Tags: javascript

This is a code snippet from Jamis Buck's Minecraft Generator. this.depth is value from 1 to 10. I understand for loops. I understand ternary operators. I don't know how to evaluate this;

```
for (z = 1, _ref = this.depth; 1 <= _ref ? z <= _ref : z >= _ref; 1 <= _ref ? z++ : z--)
```

To me, as long as _ref !< 1 it looks like this to me;

```
for (z = 1, _ref = this.depth;; 1 <= _ref ? z++ : z--)
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for any help. I have leaned alot from this site but, this is my first need to post.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this.  Is it in any way recommended?

Comment: @bozdoz I suspect this was generated by something like coffeescript.  While technically valid, it definitely doesn't look like something that was intended for people to read

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to parse the loop is :

```
for (
    z = 1, _ref = this.depth; 
    (1 <= _ref ? z <= _ref : z >= _ref);
    (1 <= _ref ? z++ : z--)
)
```

If _ref < 1, assuming that _ref is unchanged the loop is equivalent to

```
for (
    z = 1, _ref = this.depth; 
    z >= _ref; 
    z--
)
```

If _ref >= 1, assuming that _ref is unchanged the loop is equivalent to

```
for (
    z = 1, _ref = this.depth; 
    z <= _ref; 
    z++
)
```

Note that, in both cases, the reduction assumes that `_ref` is unchanged.  If your loop changes `_ref` then the reduction assumption breaks down.

Comment: I know OP had it in the example, but it should really have `var`'s in there.  Probably should avoid creating global variables.

Comment: @bozdoz if, like I expect, this was generated by something like coffeescript, there will be a line like `var z, _ref` before the loop

Comment: I guess more succinctly: the test conditions of both ternaries are the same. Isn't it the same as:

Comment: I guess more succinctly: the test conditions of both ternaries are the same. Isn't it the same as:

for(z = 1, _ref = this.depth; 1 <= _ref ? z++ : z--;)

Again, this 'mystical' code snippet belongs to Jamis Buck & can be found at: 
[link](http://jamisbuck.org/mazes/minecraft.html#).
The javascript page is at: [link](http://jamisbuck.org/mazes/js/minecraft-maze.js)
I am writing a maze generator in Unity3D c#. Consequently, I am trying to expand my knowledge by looking at how others have coded mazes. I have learned much of what I know about maze construction from Jamis Buck's blog on mazes.

Comment: @user2872985 the link appears to be part of github.com/jamis/csmazes, which was written in coffeescript and transpiled